# What is a good database structure for a website where users "follow"/"friend" other users?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a database for a web application that includes users following each other. What would be a good design? I was thinking this:

```
TABLE: users ROWS: user_id, name, pass, email, activated, user_level, registration_date
TABLE: relationships ROWS: relation_id, user_id, followed_id
```

What do you think of that?

Comment: Don't forget to index all the _id columns.

Comment: What you have there will certainly work. You haven't provided a full description of the app, so it's really not possible for others to give architecture advice. To build a good architecture, you need to understand as best you can what people are trying to accomplish, and do it in the simplest way possible. Get real users into the app as early as you can, and then it will be much more obvious if there are any architectural adjustments to be made.

Answer (score 1):

For the user table, I guess what you have is correct. If you need to add more columns, you could simply alter that table, or add an additional table with a one to one relationship.

As for the relationships table, I think that is correct. Although i wouldn't call it `followed_id`. I would suggest that you could use that table for many different types of interactions, so I would call it `user_id` and `interacter_id` and the `relationship_id` would be a number of different types of interactions (follow, poke, etc).

Comment: If that's the case, then you'd also want a relationship_type column.